# convert a column from a dataframe into a list in r

Tags: r, list

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    treeID  Z   npoints     cnvhll_          inter
3   4.0     24.877  904     206.006         3
4   5.0     24.322  1105    92.189          4
9   10.0    22.085  488     107.718         6
18  19.0    20.195  799     137.346         12
19  20.0    20.028  1597    133.829         13
```

I am converting the treeID column to list using this code

```
cliploy <- read.csv(file = 'dataframe.csv')
polylist <- cliploy["treeID"]
treepolylist <- as.list(polylist)
```

to which i get a list like this

```
$treeID
 [1]   4   5  10  19  20  21  22  26  28  33  34  36  41  42  43  44  47  49  50  53  55  57  59  60  62  67  68  74  76  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  90  91  92  94  97  99
[43] 100 105 106 108 110 111 112 125 129 133 138 139 140 145 150 153 161 169 172 176 180 190 191 197 202 210 218 219 222 224 233 237 240 246 257 269 324 325 326 327 328 331
[85] 334
```

I dont want this type of list i want something like this. How can change the type of list in r

```
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 10

[[4]]
[1] 19

[[5]]
[1] 20
```

Comment: Use `polylist <- cliploy[["treeID"]]` with double brackets to extract the vector from the column rather than subsetting to a smaller data.frame

Comment: `as.list(cliploy[["treeID"]])` gives you a list as you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so instead of this code

```
polylist <- cliploy["treeID"]
```

we can use

```
polylist <- cliploy[["treeID"]]
```

to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `purrr` approach using `map` after `group_split()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_split(treeID) %>% 
  map(., ~(.x %>% pull(treeID)))
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 10

[[4]]
[1] 19

[[5]]
[1] 20
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
 as.list(unique(df1$treeID))
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 10

[[4]]
[1] 19

[[5]]
[1] 20
```